# Initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast and comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c, pointers, null

My code fragment contains (36 and 37 are line numbers):

```
36     char* colon_unit = extract_colon_unit( zPath, path, &p_index);
37     if (colon_unit == NULL)
```

During compilation, I get a warning:

> a.c:36: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

When I remove the pointer,

```
char colon_unit = extract_colon_unit( zPath, path, &p_index );
```

it shows:

> a.c:37: warning: comparison between pointer and integer

How can I fix it?

Comment: What does `extract_colon_unit` return?

Comment: How is your `extract_colon_unit` declared? Is the declaration before the using occurrence?

Comment: Plese post declaration of extract_colon_unit().

Comment: Also, maybe rename it? It sounds like some sort of painful surgery..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the function `extract_colo_unit()` is returning a character (char) and not a character pointer (`char*`). When you change the data type of `colon_unit` to char then you won't get the first error as now the variable and the value assigned, both have the same type.

But when you compare the `colon_unit` to NULL then you are comparing a character, that is, `colon_unit` to a pointer. That is, NULL is defined as `(void*)0`, so you get the second error on line 37.

The solution totally depends on your logic and what it means to return NULL from this function. But if it's an error case or a case when there is no valid value, it simply returns 0 instead of NULL and compares against 0 in line 37.

Comment: Hi  binW. Thanks for the explanation. The function colon_unit returns the name of a directory. So, if (colon_unit == NULL) checks if the name of the directory is null. Hence I presume i cannot use if (colon_unit = 0)

Comment: @Tinyspark if function extract_colon_unit returns the name then its return type should be char* and not char and in that case you should not get any of the above errors. Can you plz add the declaration of extract_colon_unit function to your question?